# Calculate number ranges in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a map in which different number ranges are defined. User can select any range options like below,

```
var map = [
{
    'low':0,
    'high':10
},
{
    'low':10,
    'high':25
},
{
    'low':25,
    'high':50
},
{
    'low':50,
    'high':100
},
{
    'low':100,
    'high':999999
}
];
```

user selection

```
0: 0-10
1: 10-25
2: 25-50
3: 50-100
4: 100-99999
```

User can select any one range option or can select multiple too. If user selects 0: 0-10 and 1: 10-25 option then I need to set one range i.e. 0-25 (gets the low value from option 1 and higher from option 2). In the similar way there can be multiple options of selection like,

```
0,1,3,4 = 0-25 & 50-100
0,2,4 = 0-10,25-50,100-99999
```

I'm writing this algorithm in JavaScript

var map = [
{
    'low':0,
    'high':10
},
{
    'low':10,
    'high':25
},
{
    'low':25,
    'high':50
},
{
    'low':50,
    'high':100
},
{
    'low':100,
    'high':999999
}
];

function getRanges(selected) {

```
var ranges = [],already_used_range = [],low=0,high=0;
for(var i= selected.length-1;i >0; i--) { 

    console.log('i ='+i);
    if(selected[i] - selected[i-1] > 1) {
        console.log('here');

        if(!$.inArray(selected[i], already_used_range)) {
            ranges.push(map[selected[i]]);
        }
        ranges.push(map[selected[i-1]]);
        console.log(ranges);
    } else {
        console.log('here2');
        //console.log('selected.i-1 = ' + selected[i-1]);
        console.log('selected.i = ' + selected[i]);
        //var lv = i-1;
        var lv = i;
        console.log('lv =' + lv);
        console.log('selected[lv] =' + selected[lv]);

        console.log('low = ' + map[selected[lv]-1].low);
        console.log('high = ' +map[selected[i]].high);
        low = map[selected[lv]-1].low;
        if(high ==0) { 
            var hv = selected[i];
            console.log("hv =" + hv);
            high = map[hv].high;
            }

        already_used_range.push(selected[i]);
        already_used_range.push(selected[lv]-1);            
    }   
}

console.log("low = " + low);
console.log("high = " + high);
console.log("ranges");
console.log(ranges);
```

}

var selected = [2,3,4];
getRanges(selected);

var selected = [3,4];
getRanges(selected);

var selected = [2,4];
getRanges(selected);

Comment: What do you mean by needing to set a range? What is consuming this range? How will it be used? These are very important details. Not enough info provided.

Comment: Here is the algorithm... Just find the lowest of the lows and highest of the highs among selected.

Comment: So you think someone is going to do your homework for you? You didn't even try to do anything. People collaborate here, not write script on demand.

Comment: @philraj these are the options given to the user on web interface and based on these options we need to filter some records from the database. I need to identify if there are overlapping ranges available then make it single range but if not overlapping then separate ranges will be used

Comment: So where is the algorithm you are writing? Please include that so we can check what's wrong with it.

Comment: Updated the algorithm in the post

Comment: The algorithm fails on the below user inputs, var selected = [0,1,3,4];
getRanges(selected);

Answer (score -1):

Regarding your comment, here is code that would accomplish that:

```
var map = [
    {
        'low':0,
            'high':10
    },
    {
        'low':10,
        'high':25
    },
    {
        'low':25,
        'high':50
    },
    {
        'low':50,
        'high':100
    },
    {
        'low':100,
        'high':999999
    }
];

var input = [0, 1, 4] // some user input

lowest = map[input[0]]['low'] // lowest of range will be the first item of user selection
highest = map[input[input.length - 1]]['high'] // highest will be the last item of user selection
```

Comment: if the end points (high value of current item with the low value of another item) do not match then we need to pick the complete range. for [0,1,4] the result should be 0-25 and 100-9999 (two ranges) since 1 high value don't intersect with 4 low value.